# Getting an EOF error, I've searched for sytax errors cannot see

Tags: bash

Getting these two errors when running a simple script to just make a repo for a user.

This is a bash script

ERROR:

./createMyRepo.sh: line 48: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

./createMyRepo.sh: line 52: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # This script is used to automate the repo 
if [ -z `$1` ]
   then
  echo "No user was input, please input a user and try again"
  exit
   else
cd /home/$1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
echo "Successfully changed directory to user's home"
else
echo "Failed to cd directory, trying to create directory now."
mkdir /home/$1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo "Successfully created the directory location
    else
    echo "Failed to create directory, exiting."
    exit

    fi
fi
mkdir project.git
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "Succesfully created project.git directory"
else
echo "Failed to create project.git directory attempting to see if the directory already exists"
cd project.git
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo "Successfully changed to this directory"
    else
    echo "This directory cannot be created and does not exist. exiting..."
    exit

    fi
fi
cd project.git
echo "creating git repo"
git --bare init
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo "DONE Created repo"
    else
    echo "FAIL repo did not create"
    fi

fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops ... look like a typo error

```
echo "Successfully created the directory location
```

should be in this form:

```
echo "Successfully created the directory location"
```

Comment: Ah, this was it. Sometimes, you just stare at code long enough you miss all these simple things.

Answer (score 0):

The line `echo "Successfully created the directory location` is missing a `"` at the end, so that Bash is completely confused about where your strings are and aren't.

(Hat-tip to Stack Exchange's syntax highlighting, which makes the problem obvious!)

Also, I suggest you adopt a better indentation scheme; your current scheme makes it very difficult to trace nested `if`s and so on.

Comment: Yeah, I was just me basting it from shell to this site, the indentions didn't carry over. Thanks for finding the silly mistake!